# Does diamond tblastn exist?

Tags: blast, homology

I actually want to use diamond instead of blast because it is faster with small sequences and big genomes, but I actually want to make a tblastn with several protein sequences as queries and the database which will be the genome transformed by makedb.

Do you know if diamond have the tblastn option? I cannot find it.

Thank you.

Comment: We welcome new posters to SE Biology, but I must say that the obvious place to ask such a detailed technical question about software that few people will have heard of is on the website or documentation for that software. Failing that, I would email the authors of the paper cited on the website. (If you must post on SE you would be better trying SE Bioinformatics.)

Comment: Biostars.org is another very helpful Q/A site for bioinformatics.